# Can bromhexine decrease severity of respiratory diseases and viral respiratory infections such as COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, lungs, symptoms, respiratory-system

According to this article https://www.vox.com/2020/3/3/21161724/coronavirus-symptoms-covid-19-sars-cough-fever one (less frequent) symptom of COVID-19 is thick mucus from coughs (sputum). Respiratory disorders associated with viscid or excessive mucus can be treated with the mucolytic drug Bromhexine.

Therefore, does the use of bromhexine contribute anything to the treatment of COVID-19 patients? Can it be said that taking the drug ensures a generally healthier functioning of mucus in the respiratory system, and therefor positively benefit people with COVID-19 or any respiratory disorders related to viscid or excessive mucus?

*Or is this assumption (partially) false and can Bromhexine (when unnecessarily taken) cause an overly thinned mucus that causes other problems?*